# Nextjs Script tag are not loading sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

[image]

The above is the error message that comes when the script tag doesn't load. I have around 6 script tags.


I have these Scripts tags in my code; sometimes they load and sometimes they don't. But I can see them in the code if I inspect them in the browser.

```
<Script src="assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
 <Script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

I have included them in pages/_app.js and pages/_document.js, and also in some other pages just to test out but they don't work correctly.

Only after I refresh the page then they start working correctly.

OS: Linux

on windows they load properly. only on Linux I'm having this issue.

Can someone help me out with this as I need this thing resolved Quickly?

Appriciate your help.

Comment: Did you tested it in production ?

Comment: Make sure Script tag is not wrapper within <Head /> component provided by nextjs

Comment: Add screenshots.

Comment: @Sodhisaab yes I'm not including it in the<Head /> tag.

Comment: @C.Lewis I've added the screenshot of the error message above.

Comment: @Maiky, I'm currently trying to test it on Linux in production. The code was working fine in windows while I was testing it.

Comment: Same issue with "Google reCAPTCHA" on my side. It fails to load the script 1 time out of 10.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery loaded by the `<Script />` component (without `beforeInteractive`) will certainly not be available when React hydrates your page by default (If it is available during `useEffect`, then it is a bug and you should report it to Next.js).

`<Script />` component is designed to handle non-essential scripts for you (E.g., Google Analytics is only essential for website owners, but not essential for rendering the page). Thus Next.js will never load the script before React hydrates your page, resulting in a better performance and user experience.

In this case, jQuery should be considered an essential script for rendering the page, thus it shouldn't be loaded through `<Script />`.

I would recommend the following approaches:

- Includes jQuery and bootstrap in your bundle

```js
import $ from 'assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js';
import 'assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
```

- Use `beforeInteractive`

Note: `<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" />` can only be used inside a custom `_document`!

```
// _document.jsx
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
        {/** You can place it everywhere as long as it is inside a custom _document */}
        {/** And Next.js will always inject the script to the <head /> */}
        <Script
          src="assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        ></Script>
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

More details about `<Script />` component: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: @juliomalves If jQuery loaded using `<Script />` component without `strategy="beforeInteractive"`, but is available during `useEffect`, then it **Is** a bug (Non-essential scripts shouldn't block hydration!). I will make my answer clear mentioning "without beforeInteractive". Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that I was able to reproduce. I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39553) for you.